# Notebook is booting when battery is removed

Tags: boot-failure

I installed Ubuntu on my notebook, when I was using Windows it booted fine, but after change OS, sometimes it only boots if I  remove battery, is there any solution I can fix it

[Here is output of **dmesg**](http://pastebin.com/jGYmSpjG), unfortunately I couldn't paste output here it's more that 30000 charachters

Comment: please could you provide the name/make/model of notebook? also, next time you have to take out the battery, could you post the full contents of the 'dmesg' command on the terminal? this will help people to work out what is wrong and answer your question.

Comment: @thomas michael wallace I pasted output I hope It helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `dmesg` output file it appears that on boot the kernel does not recognise your battery and lists the following error message:

```
ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
```

There is a [bug report here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34532) that describes the issue you are having.

Not knowing what version of Ubuntu you are currently running or your hardware I would recommend installing a later version of Ubuntu where the kernel is a later version and checking to see if it resolves your issue, otherwise you can follow this LONG [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1775246) thread to try and solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Couldn't solve this problem so forced to back on Win7. Thanks for answer I'll try Ubuntu's latest version again.

Answer (score 0):

This very well could be a Hardware issue. When your system doesn't boot what do you see on your screen does it hang? If so is it before or after the Ubuntu screen.Believe it or not answering these questions can tell us alot.If it hangs before the Ubuntu screen its Probably a hardware issue  Does your screen stay blank. In which case could be a faulty battery or motherboard .

If its after the Ubuntu screen it could be a number of things causing this. Which we will need as much information as you can give. As in where its locking up and what your screen is showing and has showed during boot. Then maybe we can pin point what exactly has went wrong.